# Firefox refusing to play <video>

Tags: html, css

I've created a video which plays once you click a thumbnail in a lightbox (using Drupals module: Colorbox).

However it won't play in Firefox! Any advice?

Here's a link to the page: https://www.workbooks.com/video-final

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nhwz79ty/

HTML:

```
<div style="display: none;">
<div id="id-of-content">
<video id="wb_video" width="570" height="320" controls poster="/sites/default/files/image/crm-systems-poster_0.png" onclick="this.play();"/>
  <source src="/sites/default/files/image/CRM-Systems-Video.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="/sites/default/files/image/CRM-Systems-Video.mp4" type="video/mp4">

  <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/crm-system-image.png" title="CRM System image">

</video>
</div>
</div>

<div class="newvideo"><a class="colorbox-inline" href="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/CRM-Systems-Video.mp4?width=580&height=330&inline=true#id-of-content"><img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/CRM-Systems-Video.png" onclick="$('#wb_video').play();"></a></div>
```

CSS:

```
.newvideo a{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
.newvideo a:after{
    background:url(http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/play-button-crm-homepage2.png) center center no-repeat;
    bottom:0;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
.newvideo a:hover:after{
  background-image:url(http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/play-button-crm-homepage-11.png);
}
```

Comment: The given jsfiddle working fine in firefox too

Comment: Firefox 36 on the Mac plays the video without any issues.

Comment: @user check your firefox version too

Comment: Interesting I had a friend try it out and he had the same issue. Anyone tried it on Windows with Firefox 33.1?

Comment: Updated to 37.0.2 and same problem occurs. Video loads but won't play. Again on Windows.

Comment: Yes same here. In firefox fiddle works. but, in website link video play button not clickable.

Comment: Same here, in jsfiddle works but in site doesn't. Maybe it gets 2 click events and starts playing and then pauses. If you click on video you will see that it starts loading and then pause. It plays a frame every click.

Comment: Thanks gents, there was some conflicting with the javascript as @DimitrisNastos mentioned. All sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the JS 'onclick' from the img tag worked for me

```
<div class="newvideo"><a class="colorbox-inline" href="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/CRM-Systems-Video.mp4?width=580&height=330&inline=true#id-of-content"><img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/CRM-Systems-Video.png" onclick="$('#wb_video').play();"></a></div>
```

onclick="$('#wb_video').play();" - Removed this and it worked